# How can I duplicate DIV and all elements and read ASP.NET C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net

I have this form and I need duplicate or clone when the CPF/CNPJ (brazilian person identification) `onchange.` Here is what I have:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="form-row" id="Guests">
  <p><strong>Guests Forms</strong></p>
  <div id="guest1">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="labelGuestNumber" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">1.</label>
      <label for="labelGuesName1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="margin-left: 5px;">
        <input runat="server" class="form-control" id="inputGuestName1" placeholder="Guest Name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4" style="margin-left: -40px;">
      <label for="labelCPFCNPJGuest1" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">CPF/CNPJ:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input runat="server" class="form-control" id="inputCPFCNPJGuest1" placeholder="CPF / CNPJ" onChange="newGuest()" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I need read all this elements in ASP.net C# to send to database.

Comment: Have you tried something? Please post your ASP.net or C# code

Comment: I didn't make the asp.net code yet. I had a emergency in my work And can't complete the page, only thing I did was the JS code. I'm thinking to serialize into a json structure and pass by ajax post. I'll try later and post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can do it like this: clone the `<div>` with the id `guest1`, adjust all specific ids and labels based on the amount of guest divs that are already inside the div with the id `Guests` and append the clone to this div. Note that you might have a typo in the label with the attribute `for=labelGuesName1` which maybe should be `labelGuestName1` instead.

```js
function newGuest() {
  let clone = $("#guest1").clone();
  let count = $("#Guests [id^=guest]").length;
  clone.attr("id", "guest" + (count + 1));
  clone.find("label[for='labelGuestNumber']").html((count + 1) + ":");
  clone.find("label[for='labelGuesName1']").attr("for", "labelGuesName" + (count + 1));
  clone.find("#inputGuestName1").val("");
  clone.find("#inputGuestName1").attr("id", "inputGuestName" + (count + 1));
  clone.find("label[for='labelCPFCNPJGuest1']").attr("for", "labelCPFCNPJGuest" + (count + 1));
  clone.find("#inputCPFCNPJGuest1").val("");
  clone.find("#inputCPFCNPJGuest1").attr("id", "inputCPFCNPJGuest" + (count + 1));
  $("#Guests").append(clone);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="form-row" id="Guests">
  <p><strong>Guests Forms</strong></p>
  <div id="guest1">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="labelGuestNumber" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">1.</label>
      <label for="labelGuesName1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="margin-left: 5px;">
        <input runat="server" class="form-control" id="inputGuestName1" placeholder="Guest Name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4" style="margin-left: -40px;">
      <label for="labelCPFCNPJGuest1" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">CPF/CNPJ:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input runat="server" class="form-control" id="inputCPFCNPJGuest1" placeholder="CPF / CNPJ" onChange="newGuest()" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```